# Grid Return on Editable Field in Rally SDK2

Tags: javascript, rally

I have a grid with a column like this:

{ text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', editor: 'rallytextfield', flex: 2.5, sortable: false },

When I fill in information in the text field and then click somewhere else, the data is saved; however, when I hit return or tab like in a Custom Grid, nothing happens.  What can I configure to allow me to return away from this field and so get the value to save without clicking?

EDITED:  It turns out that it's to do with adding checkboxes.  If I add a selModel, the return doesn't work. If I take it away, the return works!  Here's the full app:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data:[
                { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
                { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
                { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
                { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
            ]
        });
    this.add( Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: store,
        columnCfgs: [
            { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'rallytextfield' },
            { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
            { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', editor: 'textfield' }
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        selModel: {
            injectCheckbox: 1,
            mode: 'SIMPLE'
        }
    }) );       
}
```

});

Commenting out selType & selModel and I can hit return to go from one row to the next, but with the selType & selModel in there, no return but tab does work.

Answer (score 0):

The Return/Tab inline edit navigation should be built-in without any additional configuration.  When I try to repro the issue the first thing I run into is this:

[App works as desired in debug mode but crashes in Rally environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220129/app-works-as-desired-in-debug-mode-but-crashes-in-rally-environment)

That may be the root cause since the app is likely just refreshing once the field is edited.
My working column config on my gridConfig looks like this:

```
columnCfgs: [
    'FormattedID',
    { 
        text: 'Name', 
        dataIndex: 'Name', 
        editor: 'rallytextfield', 
        flex: 2.5, 
        sortable: false 
    },
    'Owner'
],
```

Comment: Thanks, Kyle, but I think it's to do with making checkboxes.  I've edited the original.