# How to prevent page refreshing after each Card drag and drop action? (SDK 2.0p5)

Tags: rally

I have simplest implementation of CardBoard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CardBoard Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',

                launch: function() {
                    var cardBoardConfig = {
                        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                        types: ['User Story'],
                        attribute: "ScheduleState"
                    };

                    this.add(cardBoardConfig);
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'CardBoard Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Very annoying issue occurs after each drag and drop action: page refreshes.

Also I've noticed some bug that prevents page from reloading. Steps to reproduce:

1. Open page with code above;
2. Change project scope;
3. Drag and drop card;
4. You will see javascript error in browser console that prevent page from refreshing.

How can I prevent page refreshing after Card drag and drop action in case when there are no javascript Rally SDK errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by a poor handling of the [objectUpdate message](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.Message-event-objectUpdate) by the parent window. When the card is dropped, the `objectUpdate` message is fired (correctly), but the Custom HTML panel handles it by refreshing the app. I've filed a bug with Rally to fix it.

To overwrite this behavior, add this after `Rally.onReady`:

```
if(window.parent) {
    window.parent.RALLY.ui.dashboard.PanelPanel.prototype.onObjectModificationMessage = function(){};
}
```

So the entire code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CardBoard Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {

            if(window.parent) {
                 window.parent.RALLY.ui.dashboard.PanelPanel.prototype.onObjectModificationMessage = function(){};
            }

            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',

                launch: function() {
                    var cardBoardConfig = {
                        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                        types: ['User Story'],
                        attribute: "ScheduleState"
                    };

                    this.add(cardBoardConfig);
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'CardBoard Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question with a slightly different answer that should work for you as well:

[App works as desired in debug mode but crashes in Rally environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220129/app-works-as-desired-in-debug-mode-but-crashes-in-rally-environment)